# server.key lost section time i login Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I was trying to add SSL cert to my website hosted on Heroku, I followed the instructions from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint, and i successfully generated the `server.key` and `server.csr`, then I logged out the `heroku run bash`, and used the `server.csr` to generate the certificate `server.crt`, but when I came to the step `heroku certs:add server.crt server.key`, I found I forgot to download the `server.key` from Heroku, I logged in again with `heroku run bash`, and found all the intermediate files (`server.key`, `server.csr` etc.) were all gone, I am wondering where I can find those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Heroku infrastructure is designed to package and distribute an application across several machines. When you perform a command via the CLI, or you "login" into the system, you are not guaranteed to be always on the same machine.

I wonder why you performed those actions inside the Heroku environment. Generate the private key and the CSR on your machine. Once done, generate your certificate (assuming you want to use a self-signed certificate), then upload to Heroku the private key and certificate.

You could also re-key your certificate generating a new private key, a new CSR and re-keying the certificate. But it's probably easier to simply generate a new CSR, key and certificate, given you apparently self-signed it.

Note that self-signed certificates will display a security warnings, therefore are not suitable for production. If you want to use a real certificate, you need to purchase one from a Certificate Authority or reseller.

Comment: aha, i didn't realise i could generate all the intermediate files on my local box and use them generate the certificate, thank you for pointing that out, i am contacting my SSL vendor see if i could re-key my certificate.